# Is the Crimean referendum legal?

Tags: law, russian-federation, referendum, ukraine, crimea

> Как известно, Верховная Рада Крыма **в обход Конституции Украины** приняла решение о проведении в Крыму 16 марта референдума по присоединению к России. ([src](http://www.mignews.com/mobile/article.html?id=060314_163151_74623))
>
> As was noted, the [Supreme Council of Crimea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_Council_of_Crimea) made a decision **against the Ukrainian Constitution** about a referendum on 3/16/2014 to join Russia.

Is this qualifier in the newspaper true?

**Was the decision contrary to the Ukrainian Constitution** (which binds Crimean Supreme Council).

Comment: it can't possible be legal because it's a choice made under the gun of the Russian army

Comment: Interesting. How constitutional the armed takeover of power/overthrow of the legitimate president of Ukraine IS then?

Comment: It most probably is not legal. Just like it was not legal for Kosovo to declare its independency, while the legal thing would be for all of Serbia to go on referendum. But back then, it looks like USA and its allies did not care about legality.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The referendum seems to be unconstitutional. The relevant legal source appear to be article 72 and 73 of the [Ukranian constitution](http://www.president.gov.ua/en/content/chapter03.html). Article 73 states that any decisions on the territory of Ukraine must be resolved by an "All-Ukrainian referendum". Article 72 states that this type of referendum needs to be requested by at least three million citizens, "provided that the signatures in favour of the referendum have been collected in at least two-thirds of the oblasts with at least 100,000 signatures gathered in each oblast". This has not been done. Even if it had been done, *all* Ukranians would have the right to vote in the eventual referendum, whereas it seems as if only Crimean citizens would have a say in the planned referendum on March 16.

Comment: Did revolution in Ukraine was legal? If it was not, then, in fact, you cannot appeal to Ukrainian laws. If it, suddenly, was, then Crimean referrendum is of course legal - it cannot be less legal than Kievan clashes.

Comment: @user2501323 it is human right to protest against government if they dislike it!